# Android button actions

Tags: android

I create 2 different state of my button and also i create selector for this buyton:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/level1_calm" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/level1_on_click" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/level1_on_click" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/level1_calm" />
</selector>
```

But how can I use only one selector for all buttons, or it's prohibited.
I mean can I use some variable here, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/level`$Number_button`_calm" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/level`$Number_button`_on_click" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/level`$Number_button`_on_click" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/level`$Number_button`_calm" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Can i use one selector for all my buttons if they differs between themselves only in number.

Comment: @NiravRanpara Please explain how